# What is the difference using .js and .jsx as file endings for Reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, file, jsx

I would like to understand the difference between ending Reactjs file with .js and .jsx ?

I do know that JS is standard javascript, and JSX is an HTML-like syntax we use to create React components.

But I did see that if I write React component with JSX syntax and end the name of the file with .js or .jsx, they both work (seems the same way).

So what are the differences saving a React file with .js and .jsx ?

Does it affect performance ?

Will some things won't work in one way ?

Comment: they are the same, some framework use .js to store react too, how you config your compilier made them different

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok, so both are file extensions generally meant to write or define your React components. When React evolved, it brought the JSX syntax with it and developers started to write their components inside .jsx files. With the help of Babel transpilers, JSX was transpiled to JS.

Now with Babel and Webpack bundlers, you need not worry about .jsx or .js. Finally, everything will be bundled into JavaScript. And remember one thing, the web browser does not understand .jsx files or JSX syntax. It is ultimately JavaScript that runs inside the browser.

Usually, we use .jsx when your file contains only JSX and defines a User Interface, so it’s simpler for you to understand what the file will actually contain. An example below.

```
//profile.jsx
var profile = <div>  
    <img src="avatar.png" className="profile" />  
    <h3>{[user.firstName, user.lastName].join(' ')}</h3>
</div>;
```

Answer (score 5):

One of the differences is that Some code editors will understand that You are dealing with JSX syntax so they will be able to offer more help while working on React-specific code  like autocomplete abilities, type ahead etc.

Both types will work Fine for You :)